# Does the definition of the rank of a tensor change in the component-free treatment of tensors?

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

I was looking for the definition of the rank of a tensor. I found 2 different definitions depending on whether we use the component-free approach of tensors:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor:

> Definition of the rank: it is the total number of indices required to uniquely select each
>   component, which is equal to the dimension of the array. Hence a
>   scalar is of a tensor of rank 0, a vector is of a tensor of rank 1, a
>   matrix a tensor of rank 2.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_%28intrinsic_definition%29) (component-free treatment of tensors):

> Definition of the rank in this context: The term rank of a tensor
>   extends the notion of the rank of a matrix in linear algebra. The rank
>   of a matrix A is the smallest number of such outer products that can
>   be summed to produce it: $A = v w^{\mathrm{T}}$.
>
> More generally, the
>   rank of a matrix $A$ is the smallest number of such outer products
>   that can be summed to produce it: $A = v_1w_1^\mathrm{T} + \cdots +
> > v_kw_k^\mathrm{T}$

Does this mean that the definition of the rank of a tensor depends on whether we use the component-free approach to tensors?

Comment: These are two completely different uses of the work "rank". The first usage is calling elements in the tensor product of $k$ vector spaces (of equal dimension, I presume, so if the spaces are $n$-dimensional then their tensor product has dimension $n^k$) a tensor of rank $k$. The second usage is saying the rank of a tensor is the least number of elementary tensors whose sum is that tensor.

Comment: Thanks, this explains my confusion. Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept?